# Access file on S3 with GoodData File-Download?

Tags: amazon-s3, gooddata

Probably a very silly question - but I'm trying to have a GoodData project download a file from S3 for import into GoodData.

The file is uploaded to S3, and the console there gives the link in format:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/subFolder/subfolder/fileName.csv.gz.`

However when I try and access this, GoodData gives an error of 
`initilization failed.
    Error initializing file operation. Reason: No bucket name specified in the host address.`

The GoodData documentation seems to indicate the format should instead be `http://${S3_ACCESS_KEY}:${S3_SECRET_KEY}@bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.csv`

However when doing this, or 
`http://${S3_ACCESS_KEY}:${S3_SECRET_KEY}@bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/subFolder/subfolder/filename.csv`

I get that the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which component are you using? FileDownload?
If so, this works for me (I have just tried it):

```
https://${S3AccessKey}:${S3SecretKey}@${BucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/folder/filename.csv
```

Make sure that the file on S3 really exists on that path (check it by connecting there using some thirdparty tool like s3cmd or cyberduck)

If still no luck, please add some more detailed information (stacktrace, full console log, etc...)

Comment: Thanks!  I swear I'd tried it before, but doing that format is now working.